# Function keep on calling in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

This is my function, and I am getting some info in `console`. But this function keep on calling, and I am getting the `console` doing continually.
What is wrong with my code?

**Code**

```
window.onload = function () {
        var x = 0;
            var location = window.location;
            var path = window.location.pathname;

            var showIt = function () {
                if(x !=1){
                    x=1;
                    console.log(path,x);
                    window.location = path;
                }
            }
            showIt();
       }
```

Comment: `x` is not persistent between page loads, it is always `0`.

Comment: Javascript code is parsed and executed anew every time you navigate to another page

Answer (score 2):

You are reloading the page. This causes the script to run from scratch (and set `x` back to `0`). The values of variables are not persisted between page loads.

You need to store the data somewhere (e.g. in the [query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) of the URI, [local storage](http://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage) or a [cookie](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html)) and then retrieve it when you load the page (or not reload the page).